# Reading csv file from hdfs using dask and pyarrow

Tags: dask, pyarrow

We are trying out dask_yarn version 0.3.0 (with dask 0.18.2)
because of the [conflicts between the boost-cpp](https://github.com/conda-forge/arrow-cpp-feedstock/issues/59) i'm running with `pyarrow` version 0.10.0
We are trying to read a csv file from hdfs - however we get an error when running `dd.read_csv('hdfs:///path/to/file.csv')` since it is trying to use hdfs3.

> ImportError: Can not find the shared library: libhdfs3.so

[From the documentation](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/use-cases.html?highlight=pyarrow#directory-of-csv-files-on-hdfs)   it seems that there is an option to use pyarrow .

What is the correct syntax/configuration to do so?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://github.com/dask/dask-yarn/issues/20 .  In the future we would appreciate it if you did not duplicate questions.

Comment: Your right - I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the file using `locate -l 1 libhdfs.so`. In my case, the file is located under `/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/c++/Linux-amd64-64/lib`.

Then, restart your Jupyter server with the environment variable `ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR` set to this path. In my case, my command looks like:

```sh
ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR=/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/c++/Linux-amd64-64/lib jupyter lab --port 2250 --no-browser
```

Next, when you create the Yarn Cluster, pass this variable as a worker parameter:

```py
# Create a cluster where each worker has two cores and eight GiB of memory
cluster = YarnCluster(
    worker_env={
        # See https://github.com/dask/dask-yarn/pull/30#issuecomment-434001858
        'ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR': '/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/c++/Linux-amd64-64/lib',
    },
)
```

This solved the problem for me.

(Inspired by https://gist.github.com/priancho/357022fbe63fae8b097a563e43dd885b)